# OrderBy and where query is not working at the same time in firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am have almost this structure of data in my firestore and

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

I am fetching data using two queries `orderBy` and `where` but there two are not working and giving me error

[image: 3]

the piece of code i am using is this

```
 useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("accounts")
      .doc("usama_nj@gmail.com")
      .collection("glasses")
      .where("stock", ">", 0)
      .orderBy("id", "desc")
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) =>
        setGlasses(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()))
      );
  }, []);
```

if i use only single query orderBy() or where() then the query works but the combination of there query dont work together.

**Solution of the problem i want is to get the data whose stock is `greater then zero` and also order the data according to `id`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.orderBy("stock").orderBy("id", "desc")` to fix that query.

However this won't give the results you want. Instead you'll need to add a boolean field `"hasStock"` that has the same meaning as what you are querying.

Comment: can you explain it with example please i did not get it, how "hasStock == true" will work?, or did i have to use "hasStock" as orderBy("hasStock");?